# Get multiple list items by ID in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am trying to retrieve a list items from a SharePoint list but my issue is that I would like to retrieve the last four items by ID and I don't know how to proceed using JSOM.
Can someone help me whit some CAML code on how to do that?

```js
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();

//Geting reference to the list
var olist = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Configs');
var oitem = olist.getItemById(1);
//get Title,id,ConfigItem fields
ctx.load(oitem, "Title", "Id", "ConfigItem");
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {

    alert(oitem.get_item("Title"));
    alert(oitem.get_item("ConfigItem"));

}, function (a, b) {
    alert(b.get_message());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use rest api with order by and $top option for this requirement.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('chart')/items?$select=ID,Title&$orderby= ID desc&$top=4
```

Rest api get list items.

```
$.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('chart')/items?$select=ID,Title&$orderby= ID desc&$top=4",
                type: "GET",                
                headers:
                {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"                    
                },                
                success: function (data) {                    
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                        var item = data.d.results[i];
                        //to do
                    }                        
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.responseJSON.error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hello lee, thank you for your support. can I use this code directly out of the box or there are some other codes to add to the file? since I am a beginner in JavaScript, is there any other thing to do on the file?

Comment: Can I have a step by step details on how to use this code in my ShairePoint site?

Answer (score 0):

Here is JSOM solution with use of [CamlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185007(v%3Doffice.14)#retrieving-items-from-a-list-using-javascript).

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();

var query = new SP.CamlQuery()
query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>4</RowLimit></View>")

var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Configs');
var items = list.getItems(query, "ID", "Title", "FirstName", "LastName", "Level", "Grade", "Date");
var dictionary = [];

ctx.load(items);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var item = enumerator.get_current();
        dictionary.push({
            title: item.get_item("Title"),
            firstName: item.get_item("FirstName"),
            lastName: item.get_item("LastName"),
            level: item.get_item("Level"),
            grade: item.get_item("Grade"),
            date: item.get_item("Date"),
        });
    }
}, function (a, b) {
    alert(b.get_message());
});
```

Comment: Thank you Lukas for your answer. I have another question: If the list is having 5 items whit 6 columns ("Title", "Fisrt Name", "Last Name", "Level", "Grade", "Date") how can I do to retrieve those data in a list or a dictionary variable so that i can use the list else where?

Comment: @BBogo see updated answer. If you find my answer helpful, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: I was not able to retrieve data from my SharePoint list using the code you sent to me... Maybe there is something missing. I have create a new page (.aspx) in my SharePoint site called "jsTest.aspx" and I would like to retrieve data in a list within the same SharePoint site called "jsTest". I don't know what is going wrong... Please could you provide to me the entire code if something is missing? Thanks very much for your support

Comment: Yes Lukas, In fact I would like to retrieve data from 'jsTest' list including these colomns ("Title", "FirstName", "LastName", "Level", "Grade", "Date") store them in a dictionary variable and display them in a html page within the same sharepoint using javascript. please help!

Comment: Since I am new in SharePoint Can I have a step by step details on how to use thie above code in my ShairePoint site?